# Is protected member accessible from "same package non-subclass" in Java?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

I have known protected member is accessible only in its sub classes but some websites says that it's also accessible from same package non-subclasses.

Is it true?

[image: java access modifier visibility chart]

Comment: Can you share some code that illustrates the relationship between the classes that you're trying to do this with?

Comment: protected can accessed within the package

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-difference-between-package-private-public-protected-and-private

Answer (score 2):

Yep. They did that to make all the access modifiers logically "nested" in privacy.

Comment: Could you be more specific about "logically nested in privacy"?

Comment: swap the first two columns of your table and you will observe a strictly increasing collection of "yes" cases.